Formula result is different when using date from a userform
I created a form that takes inputs. When the 'Submit' button is clicked the information is loaded into a basic Excel log.
In one of the cells I have a formula that reads an array of dates and tells me if the latest date in that array is in the past or future. If any date is in the future it should read as No otherwise the output is Yes.
When I input data into the log from the form (in this example CorrectionDate) that cell containing the formula always displays as "Yes" regardless of what date I put in. If I then manually change the date in that cell the formula then works correctly.
For example if the date posted to the sheet via the form is 16/04/2024 the cell containing the below formula reads as "Yes", if I then remove the 2024 from the date and reinsert it, the cell corrects itself to "No"
The portion of code that deals with posting data as well as the formula in the sheet that reads the max date.
If CorrectionDate = "" Then
    Sheets("NCRLog").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 15) = ""
Else
    Sheets("NCRLog").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 15) = CorrectionDate
End If
 
'Adds data to the log in the next available row according to the offset from the targetrow
With Sheets("NCRLog").Range("Data_Start")
    .Offset(TargetRow, 2) = DateRaised
    .Offset(TargetRow, 3) = "Open"
    .Offset(TargetRow, 4) = OwnerCombo
    .Offset(TargetRow, 5) = InitiatedCombo
    .Offset(TargetRow, 6) = CatCombo
    .Offset(TargetRow, 7) = CatSource
    .Offset(TargetRow, 8) = Details
    .Offset(TargetRow, 9) = RiskCombo
    .Offset(TargetRow, 10) = InvestigationDue
    .Offset(TargetRow, 13) = ReportCombo
    .Offset(TargetRow, 14) = RootCombo
End With

The formula that reads the array of dates and tells me if any are in the future:
=IF(ISBLANK($P11),"",IF(MAX($P11,$Q11,$S11)>TODAY(),"No","Yes"))


I'd guess that CorrectionDate is a String, not a Date.

If your date is a String but in format which Excel accepts as date you can use -- to convert it to date (number) e.g. --$P11 > TODAY()

Thank you for the response, do I put the -- in the formula on the sheet? If so I have tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference. The output on the 'Overdue' column where this formula resides still reads as "Yes" even if the date is in the future.
